# Python ElementTree how do send the value of a variable to xml output

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I want to update the xml file with the current date in `lastrun` date attribute.
The code below results in `+ str(mprocessdate) +` and I want it to say `2015-04-16`.

What's wrong with my code? Why do I get that string instead of the actual date?

company1.xml

```
<corp>
<lastrun date="20150123" />
<company id="18888802223">
    <name>South Plantation</name>
    <P_DNIS>99603</P_DNIS>
    <Tracking_Phone>+18888802223</Tracking_Phone>
    <Account>South Plantation</Account>
    <AppendValue> Coupon</AppendValue>
    <InsertCoupon>Y</InsertCoupon>
 </company>
</corp>
```

Script

```
import datetime
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

mprocessdate = datetime.date.today()
print (mprocessdate)
tree = ET.parse("company1.xml")
mlastrun = tree.find('lastrun')
mlastrun.set('date', '+ str(mprocessdate) + ')
tree.write('company.xml')
```

Comment: Have you tried running your code?  What happens when you do?

Answer (score 1):

Leave off the `+` and just put in the variable name.

```
import datetime
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

mprocessdate = datetime.date.today()
print (mprocessdate)

tree = ET.parse("company.xml")

mlastrun = tree.find('lastrun')

mlastrun.set('date', str(mprocessdate))

tree.write('company.xml')
```